# Sublime Text Update 3083 Error - Error Code 32

Tags: sublimetext3, rename

When trying to update Sublime Text 3 to **version 3083** on a Windows 10 computer I keep getting an error message at the end of the update saying

> 'Unable to rename C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3 to C:\Program
>   Files\Sublime Text 3 (3083), error code: 32'

I looked it up on Microsoft's website and error 32 stands for *'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'*.

So I tried closing down all other programs and tried updating again but I still get the same problem. I have also tried running the program as an administrator but the update creates the same error message.

I only have package control installed and the Haxe plugin installed and so I can't find any other reason why it wouldn't work, although I haven't updated it before.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: First, is there a reason you're not using Build 3103? Second, you're not running Sublime or have any Windows Explorer windows with this directory open, are you?

Comment: I'll try but I don't think it was. I don't know why it's only downloading build 3083 but might it be because I'm not a registered user?

Comment: 3103 is the latest edition of the public beta, so you don't have to be a registered user to use it. You can get it [here](https://sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: Okay, I'll just uninstall sublime text and reinstall it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All the application is trying to do is copy the new files into the sublime program folder. You can do this yourself:

1. Close your Sublime Text program
2. Open a file browser `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Sublime Text 3\Update` (or wherever your update landed)
3. Open another `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3` (Make a backup of this folder if you want to be cautious)
4. Copy everything from the update to the `Program Files` folder
5. Run Sublime Text (you should now see the update dialog)
6. Remove the update folder and backup if everything looks good

Comment: I use portable version of Sublime Text.   I found this update folder inside data folder.  And then I followed from Step 3 and it worked for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Finally was able to do this and get rid of the frustrating error. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

For me, I found that my antivirus (Malwarebytes) was causing the issue.

(I was alerted to this because I tried to update using the installer from the website and it warned me that Malwarebytes was holding on to files it needed to complete.)

I cancelled the installer, turned off Malwarebytes, and opened sublime to let it update itself normally and it worked nicely.

It seems this is common:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/build-3143-flagged-as-virus/31272?u=spenceryue

Comment: disabled Windows Defender to workaround the issue today. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe chrome.exe (Google Chrome) was using the folder where Sublime Text was installed. Removing that lock with unlocker fixed the update error.

It's not like I have ANY plugin or open tab related to sublime text on chrome.

I really recommend unlocker though, saves you more than one time.

Answer (score 2):

I was troubled by this problem for some days on Windows 10, and resolved it at last.

1. Navicate to sublime text path, like 'C:/program files/sublime text/'
2. find 'update_installer.exe' and 'sublime_text.exe'
3. Open the file's `properties` - `compatibility` - `Run as administrator...`(Something like that, maybe the spelling is wrong)
4. Select OK, and rerun sublime text.

Comment: Right click on sublime_text.exe and select Run as Administrator, enter password and let it update. This works perfectly for v3 to v4 and keeps all your themes and settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was a package (the Powershell Editor Services package), which establishes a handle to `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3`. Those processes continued to run even after cleanly quitting Sublime Text. Killing them and removing the package that spawned them allowed Sublime Text to install its update.

I found this by using Process Explorer (procexp). Here's how:

- In procexp, run "Find Handle or DLL" (`ctrl+F`). Type "sublime" in the search field. When I did this, I saw "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3" appear several times in the search results.
- Click on one of the results in the search window. The process that has a handle on the folder will be highlighted in procexp's main window.
- Hover over the process name. You will see a Windows hint containing the command line that invoked the process. This is the command line which ran the process which had a lock on the Sublime Text 3 folder on my machine:
  `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& \"C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\PowerShell\editorservices/Start-EditorServices.ps1\" -EditorServicesVersion \"0.7.1\" -HostName \"Sublime Text Host\" -HostProfileId \"SublimeText\" -HostVersion \"3.0.3170\" -LogLevel \"Verbose\" -LogPath \"c:\users\yourus~1\appdata\local\temp\1526304355-EditorServices.log\" -BundledModulesPath \"C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\PowerShell\editorservices\modules\""`

The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices/issues/655) and has been resolved [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellEditorServices/pull/663). So, the team is being responsive. Hopefully the procedure described here will help others find and resolve similar issues, with other processes that leave unnecessary handles floating around.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was I had Sublime Text opened with another user in the same computer. I closed Sublime Text for each user and then the installer worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a plugin running in background called host plugin 3-8 and i ended it right away by clicking end process tree in task manager (Windows 7)